# requests using proxy with auth and @ in password

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests

I want do download several data from a website using pythons `requests` package. I'm sitting behind a PROXY that need authentification.
My problem is now, that my password contains the character @. I cannot change the password since the machine is used by several persons.

So if I use the syntax (according to http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/)

```
http://user:password@host/
```

So `requests` splits the password and interprets the part behind the @ as host. Is there a way to solve this? Maybe use quotes ore something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, you can manually use `HTTPProxyAuth`:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPProxyAuth

auth = HTTPProxyAuth('username', 'password')
proxy = {'http': 'http://host/'}
req = requests.get('http://www.google.com', proxies=proxy, auth=auth)
```